# Adobe Illustrator CS6: Checking "Align To Pixel Grid" Will Not Turn Off Alignment

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, pen-tool

I was wondering if there was another function that causes things like the pen tool to align to the grid.
Whenever I start a new document, nothing is aligning, which is what I'm trying to achieve. But after so many strokes are laid out over a sketch I have on a separate layer, the pen tool will then cling to the grid. When I uncheck "Align to pixel grid" under the transformation box, nothing changes. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the pixel grid and document grid are separate items, with separate snap settings.

Check in the menu `View > Snap to Grid` to turn on/off the document grid.
If it is just new objects that are snapping, also check in the Transform panel options for `Align New Objects to the Pixel Grid`.